# How can I save the increments of a ttk progressbar to a file and retrieve the increments when I re-open the app?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am working on a task manager app and I am using tkinter progress bars to keep track of past records( such as number of calls, projects, client consultations that have been completed thus far). After each new completed task, a user would click a button to increment the bar. The idea would be that the number of tasks per category of task(progress bar) are saved in a file, and read once the app is re-opened.

it looks like this
[picture of the tkinter GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq0bY.png)

I tried different things but I cannot find a working solution. Here is the code I have done so far.

I am unable to restore the value of the progress bar from previous inputs when the app was last open.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import smtplib
import os

overview = Tk()
overview.geometry("600x450")


progress1 = IntVar()
progress2 = IntVar()
progress3 = IntVar()
save1 = "progress"

list_of_files = os.listdir()


def step1():
    global ntotal
    increments = progress1.set(progress1.get() + 5)
    ntotal = int(ntotal) + int(increments)
    file = open(save1, "w")
    file.write(int(ntotal))

    if save1 in list_of_files:
        file3 = open(save1, "r")
        verified = file3.readlines()
        total = verified[0]


def step2():
    progress2.set(progress2.get() + 5)


def step3():
    progress3.set(progress3.get() + 5)


Label(overview, text="Calls", font=("Calibri", 20)).grid(row=1, column=1)
my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(overview, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500,
                              mode='determinate', variable=progress1).grid(row=2, column=1, ipady=10)
my_button = Button(overview, text="New task complete",
                   command=step1).grid(row=3, column=1)

Label(overview, text="Client Consultations",
      font=("Calibri", 20)).grid(row=4, column=1)
my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(overview, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500,
                              mode='determinate', variable=progress2).grid(row=5, column=1, ipady=10)
my_button = Button(overview, text="New task complete",
                   command=step2).grid(row=6, column=1)

Label(overview, text="Group projects", font=(
    "Calibri", 20)).grid(row=7, column=1)
my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(overview, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500,
                              mode='determinate', variable=progress3).grid(row=8, column=1, ipady=10)
my_button = Button(overview, text="New task complete",
                   command=step3).grid(row=9, column=1)


overview.mainloop()
```

Comment: Save its progress to a file then load that file when needed.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Are you struggling with writing to a file? Reading from a file? Getting the current value of the progress bar? Restoring the value of the progress bar? Something else?

Comment: I am unable to restore the value of the progress bar from previous inputs when the app was last open.